# DownloadUrl missing from metadata for file on Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to download a file from the Google Drive API but there is no DownloadUrl field.

[Download Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads#examples)

```
var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];

                    var request = gapi.client.request({
                        'path': '/drive/v2/files/' + doc.id,
                        'method': 'GET',
                    });

                    request.execute(function (resp) {
                        addToFileCallback(resp);
                    });
```

Comment: what is the mime type of the file you are downloading?

Comment: Anything doesnt matter

Comment: "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet", "application/vnd.google-apps.document"

Comment: native google file types such as those you've mentioned don't have downloadUrls, they have an array of exportLinks. This is because their format is proprietary thus it wouldn't make any sense to download them. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

Comment: So best case scenario, check mime type and do conditional on which export link to use?  Also post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native google file types such as those you've mentioned don't have downloadUrls, they have an array of exportLinks. This is because their format is proprietary thus it wouldn't make any sense to download them. See developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

There isn't really a need to check the mime type. Just use whichever of downloadUrl or an appropriate exportLink is present. Remember that the downloadUrl is short lived.

It's useful to use https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it or http://www.clevernote.co/app/drivecrud.html to get a close look at the export links that are available for any given doc type.