# GoogleDrive downloadURL is not populating

Tags: asp.net, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to integrate Google-docs UI with ASP.NET Web application.

In this files are stored on our file storage and We want to open Google Docs Editor to edit the word/excel/PPT files.

As a part of POC for this requirement, I am doing below:

1. Uploading file into Google Drive using below code:

   ```
   Dim objInsert As Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload = objDriveService.Files.Insert(objFile, objStream, sMimeType)
   objInsert.Convert = True
   objInsert.Upload()
   ```
2. Getting response after upload and using `objFile.AlternateLink`
   property to open the Editor to edit file.
3. I am facing the issue to download the file when I am using
   `objInsert.Convert = True`. when I am making the call to File object
   my Download URL (`objFile.DownloadUrl`) is not returning it is set
   with **Null**.  If I don't use the `objInsert.Convert = True` then I
   am getting Download URL but problem is then *AlternateLink* open the
   file in View mode with various option, I want the URL to open it
   directly in editor.

Please suggest what am I missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: this was already asked here: [DownloadUrl missing from metadata for file on Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413429/downloadurl-missing-from-metadata-for-file-on-google-drive-api)

I think it is the expected behaviour. You can't directly download a Google file type, you have to export it to some compatible format.